# How to correct the "Invalid destructuring assignment target" as I list Ids after the "AddStudentIds" key in a Google script for Classroom

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In the Google script I am writing, I managed to create the ClassRoom CourseWork but I could not fix the problem I find with `modifyAssignees`.
Apparently the problem is in the assignement of the Ids to `AddStudentIds` but I actually do not understand what the error message "Invalid destructuring assignment target" means. Many thanks

```js
var CW = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork, "<courseId>");
Logger.log("id: " + CW.id);
CW.modifyAssignees({
    AssigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENT",
    ModifyIndividualStudentsOptions({
      AddStudentIds: ["<studentId>@studenti.uniss.it"]
    })
  },
  "36808162602",
  CW.id);
```

Comment: The object map in your first parameter to `modifyAssignees` is malformed.  The second property of that object map is calling a function `ModifyIndividualStudentsOptions`, but does not declare a property name.

Answer (score 2):

Names of some of the properties are the wrong case.  First parameter object map was malformed.

```js
var CW = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork, "<courseId>");
Logger.log("id: " + CW.id);
var mar = {
  assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS",
  modifyIndividualStudentsOptions: {
    addStudentIds: ["<studentId>@studenti.uniss.it"]
  }
};
var CWa = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.modifyAssignees(mar, "<courseId>", CW.id);
```

Based off Google Classroom API reference:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/modifyAssignees

If you use the "Try this API" panel on the right (specifically the "Request body" section), you can see how you are supposed to format the configuration objects for the API calls, which also had the wrong names.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand the error message (as well as terms like 'malformed object map' or 'does not declare a property name', excuse my ignorance) but thanks to your comments and answers I finally got to the following functioning code.

```js
var CW = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork, "<courseId>");
Logger.log("id: " + CW.id);
var mar = {
  assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS",
  modifyIndividualStudentsOptions: {
    addStudentIds: ["<studentId>@studenti.uniss.it"]
  }
};
var CWa = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.modifyAssignees(mar, "<courseId>", CW.id);
```

Comment: Other answers were useful but not complete, "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS", as an example, was missing the final S.

Comment: Hm, well you can accept your own answer.  In all fairness, I did address the problem/error you were asking about (and more).  But, I could only fix and point out the general Javascript errors, but as I don't have access to the environment where the code is run on, there wasn't any way for me to validate the actual API specific inputs.  Although I did point out the API reference, because it was clear that the API calls were probably incorrect.  I've updated my own answer to fix the API errors that you have adjusted in there.

Comment: To explain "malformed object map", what I meant was that the syntax was wrong: `{ assignee: "", modifyBlah({}) }` is invalid syntax for declaring an object map, because the `modifyBlah` area does not have a property name.